# Xcode Binary Rejected : Entries are not retained after the app is closed

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, binary

2.2

We found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed on iPad running iOS 7.1.1 and iPhone 5s running iOS 7.1.1, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, entries are not retained after the app is closed.

For discrete code-level questions, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. When the DTS engineer follows up with you, please be ready to provide:

- complete details of your rejection issue(s)
- screenshots
- steps to reproduce the issue(s)
- symbolicated crash logs - if your issue results in a crash log

If you have difficulty reproducing a reported issue, please try testing the workflow as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/Technical Q&A QA1764: How to reproduce a crash or bug that only App Review or users are seeing.

---

The app works perfectly fine on an iPhone 5s, iPhone 4 and even on the iOS Simulator [every version].

The only time it's not saving is when I'm currently running a build on the simulator, the data is not saved.

But when I open the app back up on the simulator not running a build, the app works fine and it's able to save. Is this somehow my fault? I'm was working on xCode 5.0.2 now I updated to 5.1.1 just to see if there was any changes.

Comment: This question could be off-topic because it is about the Apple AppStore validation process, and not a programming-centric problem

Comment: It is not possible for anyone to tell you why your app doesn't save data since you haven't told us anything useful. Did you test your app clean by deleting any test builds from your device and then deploy an AdHoc build? Does that save data?

Comment: Are you "saving" data in the bundle?  The bundle is read-only on real devices.